# conceptualizing noSQL... using Magic the Gathering

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

So, I've been using SQL for ever. It's all I know, really, but I really want to understand how  to conceptualize document data.

```
{
  "MBS":{
    "name":"Mirrodin Besieged",
    "code":"MBS",
    "releaseDate":"2011-02-04",
    "border":"black",
    "type":"expansion",
    "block":"Scars of Mirrodin",
    "cards":[
      {"layout":"normal",
      "type":"Creature — Human Knight",
      "types":["Creature"],
      "colors":["White"],
      "multiverseid":214064,
      "name":"Hero of Bladehold",
      "subtypes":["Human", "Knight"],
      "cmc":4,
      "rarity":"Mythic Rare",
      "artist":"Austin Hsu",
      "power":"3",
      "toughness":"4",
      "manaCost":"{2}{W}{W}",
      "text":"Battle cry (Whenever this creature attacks, each other attacking creature gets +1/+0 until end of turn.)\n\nWhenever Hero of Bladehold attacks, put two 1/1 white Soldier creature tokens onto the battlefield tapped and attacking.",
      "number":"8",
      "watermark":"Mirran",
      "rulings":[
        {"date":"2011-06-01", "text":"Whenever Hero of Bladehold attacks, both abilities will trigger. You can put them onto the stack in any order. If the token-creating ability resolves first, the tokens each get +1/+0 until end of turn from the battle cry ability."},
        {"date":"2011-06-01", "text":"You choose which opponent or planeswalker an opponent controls that each token is attacking when it is put onto the battlefield."},
        {"date":"2011-06-01", "text":"Although the tokens are attacking, they never were declared as attacking creatures (for purposes of abilities that trigger whenever a creature attacks, for example)."}
      ],
      "imageName":"hero of bladehold",
      "foreignNames":[
        {"language":"Chinese Traditional", "name":"銳鋒城塞勇士"}, 
        {"language":"Chinese Simplified", "name":"锐锋城塞勇士"},
        {"language":"French", "name":"Héroïne de Fortcoutel"}, 
        {"language":"German", "name":"Held der Klingenfeste"}, 
        {"language":"Italian", "name":"Eroina di Rifugio delle Lame"},
        {"language":"Japanese", "name":"刃砦の英雄"},
        {"language":"Portuguese (Brazil)", "name":"Herói de Bladehold"}, 
        {"language":"Russian", "name":"Герой Блэйдхолда"}, 
        {"language":"Spanish", "name":"Héroe de Fortaleza del Filo"}
      ], 
      "printings":["Mirrodin Besieged"]},
      {next card...},
      {next card...},
      {next card...},
      {last card...}
    ]
  },
  {next set...},
  {next set...},
  {last set...}
}
```

So, I have a json file of all of the cards from Magic: The Gathering. The json is 'segmented' into the different sets. So, if I were to import this somehow into a noSQL database (mongoDB):

what would constitute a document?

Is each set a document?

Is each card a document?

What would be a good structure?

How does the querying work at that point... is it just a giant 'text search' if I'm looking for something?

Just looking for some sort of insight to wrap my head around noSQL.

Comment: The JSON is valid-ish but it would depend on what you would like to do with the data from your cards. As you have structured things at the moment you have a large document with all your cards in a sub-array rather than as documents. The structure depends on how you want to use this data, can you provide some more insight into what you'd like to use it for ?

Comment: I'd want to have a database for searching for the cards, individually. I built a similar site (that's not up) that just shows the actual cards, with no BS. I'm rebuilding it, and wanted to try my hand at noSQL. I hate to answer a question with a question, but how *should* I structure it?

Comment: Before I'd answer that, I'll have to ask another question/s but primary what are you intending to query using your site / what will be the frequent questions you'll ask regarding the data stored about the cards?

Comment: `cards[:name]`, `cards[:colors]`, `cards[:type]`

Comment: That type of queries are possible with a noSQL database. Here is an example of four different use case designs, http://www.slideshare.net/friedo/data-modeling-examples and there is a good PDF on how to design your model - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/MongoDB-data-models-guide.pdf Walking through these documents from your own application's viewpoint will help you understand how you should structure your database.